# QGraphicsItem.setPos() in PyQt5 / Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I'm struggeling to understand the QGraphicsItem.setPos() method in PyQt5 / Qt. I think it goes back to me not understanding the cordinate system of QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene, I tried to do some research, but I haven't found the explanation.

Below is a simple test application. After adding the QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView, I do the following:

1. I add an Ellipse with (100, 100, 20, 20)
2. I add an Ellipse with (100, 100, 20, 20) and call setPos(50, 50) afterwards.

I would think, that both ellipses will be created at x=100, y=100, with a size of (20, 20).
When calling setPos(50, 50) I would expect it to be at scene coordinates x=50, y=50, but it is at x=150, y=150, essentially adding to the start position.

The documentation of QGraphicsItem.setPos() only states, that it sets the position in parent coordinates, meaning scene coordinates, since the ellipses have no parent.

I would appreciate an explanation, many thanks!

WORKING TEST APPLICATION (Pyton / PyQt5)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.title = "setPos() Example"
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600

        # Init UI
        self.canvas = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphics_view = QGraphicsView(self.canvas, self)
        self.graphics_view.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

        self.canvas.addLine(100, 100, 200, 200)  # For reference

        ellipse1 = self.canvas.addEllipse(100, 100, 20, 20, QPen(Qt.black), QBrush(Qt.blue))
        ellipse1.setPos(50, 50)

        ellipse2 = self.canvas.addEllipse(100, 100, 20, 20, QPen(Qt.black), QBrush(Qt.red))

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's actually explained in the documentation about [`addEllipse()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addEllipse): "Note that the item's geometry is provided in item coordinates, and its position is initialized to (0, 0)." This is even more clear in the `addRect()` docs: "For example, if a QRect(50, 50, 100, 100) is added, its top-left corner will be at (50, 50) relative to the origin in the item's coordinate system." When you create an ellipse with `100, 100, 20, 20`, the ellipse *item* is *displayed* at `100, 100` but *relative* to the item position `0, 0`. This means that if you »

Comment: » call `setPos(50, 50)` then the ellipse rectangle will still be at `100, 100` (the original rectangle) in local coordinates, but since it's been *positioned* at `50, 50` then it will be shown *translated* to that position: `pos.x() + rect.x()` is `50 + 100` and `pos.y() + rect.y()` also becomes `50 + 100`, giving the rectangle being *displayed* in *scene coordinates* at `150, 150`. That's why you have two options to "set the position" of a rectangle/ellipse: using `setPos` and `setRect`, which may give similar *visual results* but logically different positioning. If you want to create a »

Comment: » rectangle that always has its top left corner coinciding with its position, then always create it with its geometry at `0, 0`, *then* call `setPos` with the actual coordinates in which you want it. In your case: `addEllipse(0, 0, 20, 20)` and `setPos(50, 50)`. Note that the same concept also applies to `addLine()`. I suggest you to do some research about basic concepts ot Euclidean geometry and Cartesian coordinate system, including *relative* coordinates.